# How can i use firefox in browser preveiw?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the "browser preview" extension for VS code, but it is trying to use chrome. I was wondering how i could get it to use Firefox instead. I have also tried to use edge, but can't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Isnt the extension using your default browser?

Comment: it tries to open chrome, but i am using Firefox.

Comment: it seems to me, that the extension is designed to use chrome so mayme you need different extention for firefox